# How to get Entity from DB including navigation properties and child list total amount

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have next entity

```
public class Objective
{
    public virtual UserInfo AssignedUser { get; set; }
    public int? AssignedUserID { get; set; }
    public string ObjectiveText { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveTask> Tasks { get; set; }
    public virtual UserInfo User { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

One objective could has one Assigned User and one User but many Tasks.

After getting Entity from DB I map it to DTO class which looks like this

```
public class ObjectiveListViewModel
{
    public string AssignedString { get; set; }
    public string ObjectiveText { get; set; }
    public int TasksCount { get; set; }
    public string UserContactName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping settings doesn't meter

When I do this with query like this

```
(from objective in context.Set<Objective>() select objective)
.Include(o => o.User)
.Include(o => o.AssignedUser)
.ToListAsync();
```

Everything works cool - User and Assigned User properties are loaded and no need do extra query to DB to get their data.

But I need return objectives with tasks amount. 
To do this I've created a generic class

```
public class EntitySubCount<TEntity>
{
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public int GroupCount { get; set; }
}
```

And use it in this way

```
(from objective in context.Set<Objective>() select objective)
.Include(o => o.User)
.Include(o => o.AssignedUser)
.Select(o=> new EntitySubCount<Objective> { 
    Entity = o, 
    GroupCount = o.Tasks.Count })
.ToListAsync();
```

But User and Assigned User properties are not loaded and it require additional query to DB to get their data.
I understand that it because lazy loading.

The question is - how I can get from DB my Entity with loaded nav. properties and with count of Tasks at once?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. No need for the includes if you are projecting. In this case I project to an anonymous type, but you could create a ViewModel class to project to if desired.

```
var objectiveList = context.Objectives
    .Select(o => new 
    {
        Entity = o,
        // or you could just pick the properties:
        ObjectiveText = o.ObjectiveText,
        User = o.User,
        AssignedUser = o.AssignedUser,
        GroupCount = o.Tasks.Count 
    }).ToList();
```

EDIT: I see you already have a ViewModel(DTO). You might be looking for something like this:

```
var objectiveList = context.Objectives
    .Select(o => new ObjectiveListViewModel
    {
        AssignedString = o.AssignedUser.Name,
        ObjectiveText = o.ObjectiveText,
        TasksCount = o.Tasks.Count 
        UserContactName = o.User.Name
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Steve for your help. Yes, it will works and I know about this solution. I was just thinking if it's possible to avoid projecting query result to DTO. But maybe it could be better to not invent anything new and use simple and working solution.

Comment: Another way is to fetch your entity and then use a tool like Automapper to populate your DTO/ViewModel. In fact, it has an [extension](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) where you can do both in 1 step with `.Project().To<ObjectiveListViewModel>`.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I use Automapper in my project to map Entities to ViewModels in a Web project but have not know that it works with IQueryable. Thank you a lot, it opens new opportunities for me :)